# Date in TitleForHeaderInSection (UITableViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Perhaps my question will seem very easy, but because I recently studied Swift that is some problem that I can not solve.

The problem is with the `UITableViewController`, namely the titleForHeaderInSection methods.

I have a list of events and depending on their creation date (day, month, year) they should appear in a sorted list in the `TableViewController`.

An example of the screen that I want to get:

```
March 2019 (current year)
EventOne 21.03.2016
Event Two 05.03.2018

July 2019 (current year)
Event One 01.07.2016
Event Two 01.07.2011

December 2019 (current year)
EventOne 01.12.2000
Event Two 21.12.1998
```

I would be very grateful for your help

Here is my code:

---

```swift
import UIKit

class ToDoListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var toDoList: Dictionary<TimeInterval, Array<String>> = [:]
    var sortedSections = [TimeInterval]()

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let dateDouble = self.sortedSections[section]
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: dateDouble)
        let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
        dateformatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"

        return dateformatter.string(from: date as Date)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return self.sortedSections.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.toDoList[sortedSections[section]]!.count

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        let todoArray = toDoList[sortedSections[indexPath.section]]!
        cell.textLabel?.text = todoArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func save(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    }

    @IBAction func cancel(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    }
}
```

---

```swift
import Foundation

struct Task {
    var name: String?
    var date: String?
}
```

---

```swift
class NewItemTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var newToDoTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dueDateTextField: UITextField!

    var tasks = Task()

    @IBAction func textFieldEditing(_ sender: UITextField) {

        let datepickerView = UIDatePicker()
        datepickerView.datePickerMode = .date
        sender.inputView = datepickerView

        datepickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

     @objc func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {

        let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
        dateformatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dateformatter.timeStyle = .none
        dueDateTextField.text = dateformatter.string(from: sender.date)
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let identifier = segue.identifier else { return }

        switch identifier {
        case "save":

            tasks.name = newToDoTextField.text!
            tasks.date = dueDateTextField.text!

            let todoListTableViewController = segue.destination as! ToDoListTableViewController

            if let newItem = tasks.name {

                if let dueDateString = tasks.date {

                let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
                dateformatter.dateStyle = .medium
                dateformatter.timeStyle = .none

            if let dueDate = dateformatter.date(from: dueDateString) {

                let dueDate = dueDate
                let dateString = dueDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

                if todoListTableViewController.toDoList[dateString] == nil {
                    todoListTableViewController.toDoList[dateString] = [newItem]
                } else {                                              todoListTableViewController.toDoList[dateString]?.append(newItem)
                }
            }
        }
    }

            todoListTableViewController.sortedSections.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

            todoListTableViewController.sortedSections = todoListTableViewController.toDoList.keys.sorted(by: >)

            todoListTableViewController.tableView.reloadData()

        case "cancelSegue":
            print("Cancel tapped")

        default:
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Perhaps my question will seem very easy" and **what's your question?** sort the data? show the title of the section?

Comment: Sorry, the question just forgot to add :)
How to make the section display the month of the event creation and the current year, depending on the created events?

Comment: So from your code I'm guessing the todos are not being grouped, correct?

Comment: Yes. They will be grouped only if there is the same date (day, month, year) completely